# Maintain list selected checkbox in generic function

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a lot of datatables in my app. Every table has a checkbox column, with on the header a "master" checkbox to check/uncheck all.

To keep from copy/pasting the code handling the check/uncheck, I made a closure in my main app.

But I need to keep a state of the selected checkbox, for the displayed page (which has it own js script).

How to make this generic enough ?

Here is a sample (I handle a lot more stuff in the main app)

```
var App = (function () {
    var handleDataTables = function () {
        var table;
        table = $('.dataTable');
        table.aSelected = [];
        table.on('draw.dt', function (e, settings, json) {
            handleUniform();
        });
        table.on('xhr.dt', function (e, settings, json) {
            $(this).add('.group-checkable').change(function () {
                var set, group_checked;
                set = $(this).attr("data-set");
                group_checked = $(this).is(":checked");

                $(set).each(function () {
                    if (group_checked) {
                        $(this).prop('checked', true);
                        if ($.inArray($(this).attr("value"), table.aSelected) === -1) {
                            table.aSelected.push($(this).attr("value"));
                        }
                    } else {
                        $(this).prop('checked', false);
                        table.aSelected.pop($(this).attr("value"));
                    }
                });
                $.uniform.update(set);
            });

            $(this).add('.checkboxes').change(function (e) {
                var checked;
                checked = $(e.target).is(":checked");
                console.log(table.DataTable);
                if (checked) {
                    if (table.aSelected.length === table[0].rows && !$(this).add('.group-checkable').parent().hasClass("checked")) {
                        $(this).add('.group-checkable').parent().addClass('checked');
                    }
                    console.log($.inArray($(e.target).attr("value"), table.aSelected));
                    if ($.inArray($(e.target).attr("value"), table.aSelected) === -1) {
                        table.aSelected.push($(e.target).attr("value"));
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($(this).add('.group-checkable').parent().hasClass("checked")) {
                        $(this).add('.group-checkable').parent().removeClass('checked');
                    }
                    table.aSelected.pop($(e.target).attr("value"));
                }
                console.log(table.aSelected);
                table.display_btns();
            });
        });
    });

    return {
        //main function to initiate template pages
        init: function () {
            handleDataTables();
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks !

Comment: Still haven't found how to proceed...